# Export neo4j graph for a d3 visualisation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, neo4j

I am currently develloping a webservice to visualize neo4j graph on a html webpage. I use bolt driver to establish the connection with my database using javascript.

However even if I succeed to install "Apoc" plugin to export  data to JSON format it's not d3 ready, furthemore I am not able to parse the data to a d3 format...

If anyone has any idea how I could retrieve a "nicer" format. like

[nodes{},
 links{}]

Comment: Check out https://github.com/eisman/neo4jd3